# Using variable references to fields in a template

Tags: templating, variable, array

I have a situation where [Matrix within Matrix](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/812) would be ideal, but instead we've ended up with a Matrix row that has pairs of fields up to a maximum of 6:

```
quote1
attribution1
…
quoteN
attributionN
…
quote6
attribution6
```

Rather than work through each pair…

`{% if matrixBlock.quote1|length %} {# quote 1 stuff #} {% endif %}
…
{% if matrixBlock.quote6|length %} {# quote 6 stuff #} {% endif %}`

…I thought I might be able to use a variable reference to numbers 1 to 6:

```
{% set quotes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] %}

{% for n in quotes %}
    {% set nText = 'quote' ~ n %}
    {% set nCite = 'attribution' ~ n %}

    <blockquote>
        {{ matrixBlock.nText|md }}
        <cite>{{ matrixBlock.nCite }}</cite>
    </blockquote>
{% endfor %}
```

…but although `{{ dump(nText) }}` confirms the reference string is being parsed correctly, the string is clearly invalid as a field reference.

Is there a way to get this done to achieve a nice terse template (not the end of the world if I can't)?

I have a sense that Twig's [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) function might help, but I can't join the dots.

Comment: If you're looking to nest Matrix fields I highly recommend the [Neo plugin](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-neo).

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
{% for n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] %}
    {% if attribute(matrixBlock, 'quote' ~ n)|length %}
    <blockquote>
        {{ attribute(matrixBlock, 'quote' ~ n) }}
        <cite>{{ attribute(matrixBlock, 'attribution' ~ n) }}</cite>
    </blockquote>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [subscript syntax](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) which is slightly more terse. And to iterate over a sequence of numbers, you can use the `..` operator instead of listing the whole array.

```
{% for n in 1..6 %}
    {% if matrixBlock['quote' ~ n]|length %}
    <blockquote>
        {{ matrixBlock['quote' ~ n] }}
        <cite>{{ matrixBlock['attribution' ~ n] }}</cite>
    </blockquote>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```